# How to store and display values

Tags: matlab

Consider

```
a=2
b=10
z=[...]          %variable
p=[...]          %variable
while a<b
      a=a+1;
      .....;
      .....;
      f=...;    %some objective function
      Q=max(f);
      z=z(f==Q)
      p=p(f==Q)
      pause
end
```

How do i store and display the values of z and p that are being calculated in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Uhm, just remove the semicolon (`;`) at the end of the statements that calculate `z` and `p`. Alternatively, write `z, p` inside the loop, just before `pause`. **Pro top**: it seems that you didn't grasp the MATLAB basics. There are plenty of friendly tutorials online that you are recommended to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why you're using a `while` loop. You can create a variable `ii`, similiar to your `a`, but starting with `1`, in every iteration and store the values like that:

```
z(ii)=z(f==Q);
ii=ii+1;
```

or just use a `for`-loop:

```
a=2
b=10
z=[...]          %variable
p=[...]          %variable
for ii=a:1:b-1
      a=a+1;
      .....;
      .....;
      f=...;    %some objective function
      Q=max(f);
      z(ii)=z(f==Q)
      p(ii)=p(f==Q)
end
```